# Switching component in Nest Thermostat?

Tags: switching

Does anyone know what the team at Nest Thermostat uses as the switching mechanism for the thermostat? I would like to build my own DIY Thermostat utilizing the ESP32 as a learning project. I have searched and found some Mosfets that could work along with some Relays however would really like to keep the project small and compact. Therefor these components would be to large. Would love to know if there is a surface mount component possibly multi channel that could easily replace the above items to perform the 24v switching task? Thanks!

Comment: Rather than asking what the Nest thermostat uses specifically, you may want to ask what is a suitable switch is for a thermostat in general, or even better, ask what the typical furnace needs (I'm pretty sure it's a dry contact form A switch that can handle 24VAC at no more than half an amp -- but I'm just guessing on the current based on the mechanical thermostats I've had apart, and the wire sizes that thermostats are wired with).

Comment: Most thermostats do use miniature magnetically-latching relays - about 20x10x8mm. Most furnaces/HVAC use a 24VAC supply for the fan and valve control circuits, so you need a switch that works bi-directionally - series source-to-source connected FETs, or there are many DIP package solid state relays you could look at.

Answer (score 1):

Use google to search for "Nest thermostat teardown". Many teardowns show there are no relays inside so it might not even use "switching" (like most traditional thermostats do), the Nest can use a protocol like [OpenTherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenTherm).

Protocols like OpenTherm allow finer control of the heating system. Instead of just on/off there will also be commands like "20% of full capacity" to prevent "overshoot" and making the heating more efficient.

For a DIY thermostat however it is **much** easier to use the traditional on/off switching. Usually this is done using a **relay**. Even more convenient is a **latching relay**, which only needs to be energized (and use power) when it switches on or off. That way it is possible to make a thermostat that runs on batteries. A non latching relay would quickly drain the batteries as it needs to be energized all the time when it needs to be on.

It should be very well possible to use some solid-state switch instead of the relay like a MOSFET which also does not require power to be kept on.

Comment: Honeywell uses miniature latching Relays https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189?FV=ffe000bd%2Ca8c0003%2Ca8c0004%2Cmu1A%7C1410%2Cmu200mA%7C1410%2Cmu250mA%7C1410%2Cmu400mA%7C1410%2Cmu500mA%7C1410%2Cmu50mA%7C1410%2C1f140000&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Nests, or atleast the Nest E uses a cmos analog switch or multiplexer like the TI LW051A 1161014 https://www.edn.com/tale-of-two-thermostats-nest-teardown/

But the Nest can target multiple types of heating systems and uses multiple boards so who knows what they use for what system.

That said, standard mechanical relays can be tiny. Like the size if a few resistors or a dip socket.

[image] source: http://www.vaneijndhoven.net/jos/relaixedsmd/

Some omron brand sub miniature relays are only 10 mm long, 6mm heigh. You would still need a driver as your typical microcontroller output wouldn't drive a relay directly (you might get away with a 5V 20mA coil if you had a 5V microcontroller but you don't, also inrush current and flyback when turning off, better to use a fet or npn transistor) But a smd mosfet and relay and resistors and diode could be made into a dime size section of a pcb. Not sure how small you trying to get to.

Comment: It does look like [LW051A gets used](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nest+Learning+Thermostat+2nd+Generation+Teardown/13818), but I am confused because the datasheet only allows the mux to operate up to 7V.  So, how does the Nest allow the standard +/-24V RMS operation?  I wonder if there are relays inside the Nest after the mux.

Answer (score 0):

I you look at the Nest patents, you will see that they use back-back connected high V FETs. These block AC current, and because of voltage spikes and other transients are rated at much higher than 24 V (this has a peak of 34 theoretically, but 80 V or 100 V devices would be necessary).

If you use a triac (which would work), the power dissipation would raise the thermostat's temperature, and so it would not correctly regulate the air temperature. Similarly, while building your own thermostat, you need to keep power consumption very low -- not to save battery life, but to avoid any detectable self-heating of the unit.